# A compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ of positive Lebesgue measure such that $m(K \cap I) < |I|$ for every interval $I$ of positive length

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> There exists a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ of positive Lebesgue measure such that $m(K \cap I) < |I|$ for every interval $I$ of positive length

For this question, I am thinking about using a fat Cantor set *K* . I know there is no interval contained in a fat Cantor set *K* . But how to proceed to argue that $m(K \cap I) <|I|$ then?

**Source**: it's an exercise from Tao's book.

Comment: what is $m$? How about $I$ Your question is missing context.

Comment: @mathemagician, *m* denotes the lebesgue measure and *I* is just an interval.

Comment: There should be something wrong with your problem, $m(K\cap I)$ is always less than $m(I)$, at least weakly.

Comment: @mathemagician The (slightly) non-trivial part is the strict inequality.

Comment: @user119758 What do you know about $I\setminus K$?

Comment: @mathemagician, it is certainly trivial that the weak inequality holds, but the problem is to find a compact set so that the strict inequality holds for every interval. It's an exercise from Tao's book.

Comment: I see. I think in that case your "Fat Cantor Set" approach should work. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @DanielFischer, could you please enlighten me a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @user119758 If you know that $m(I\setminus K) > 0$, then?

Comment: One noteworthy property of a Cantor set is that it's "nowhere dense". What does that mean? Can you prove that, if $S\subseteq I$ and $m(S)=m(I)$, then $S$ is dense in $I$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, actually what I cannot figure out is exactly how to prove $m(I\K)>0$...

Comment: @user119758 Well, what do you _know_ about $I\setminus K$? (Without loss of generality, assume that $I$ is an open interval.)

Comment: @DanielFischer, if *I\K* is an open set, it can be written as unions of disjoint intervals.Thus we have $m(I\K)>0 $, am I right? But the empty set is also an open set, its measure is still $0$ .

Comment: If you read your question, you will find a reason why $I\setminus K \neq \varnothing$ [unless $I =\varnothing$ of course, but then you cannot have a strict inequality anyway].

Comment: @DanielFischer, thank you very much for your patience and help! I think I fully understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the main points made in comments:

1. Every nonempty open set has positive length.
2. For every open interval, $I\setminus K$ is open.
3. If $I\setminus K$ is empty, then $K$ contains $I$, so it has nonempty interior.
4. Fat Cantor sets have empty interior.